# Math History: Who was the first to use the word "map" in its modern meaning in Mathematics?

Tags: general-topology, functions, math-history

So far the first explicit mention of the word map to describe sets or in connection with functions i found was in the Paper "Homotopy Relations in Fibre Spaces" by W. Hurewicz and N. E. Steenrod from 1941.
But so far i could not find a comprehensive etymological analysis of the word map or mapping in mathematics. 
My suspicion so far is that it emerged through the course of the four colour theorem since there was at first a "real map" wich was solved using sets.
Any help on this topic would be widely appreciated.

Comment: There is the real possibility that it was used orally before appearing in print.

Comment: See [mapping](http://jeff560.tripod.com/m.html) in Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (M).

Comment: Thanks everyone it seems that it was indeed the translation of Kantors "Abbildung" into the "mapping" of Morley in this Paper:http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1904-005-04/S0002-9947-1904-1500685-7/S0002-9947-1904-1500685-7.pdf from 1904. 
As of yet Mathematics seems to be the first in the modern Evolution of the Word Map with Biology coming in second in 1913 with A. H. Strutevants "Gene-mapping"

Answer (score 6):

See [mapping](http://jeff560.tripod.com/m.html) in Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (M).

For Hermann Weyl, see [H.Weyl (1929), page 110](https://books.google.it/books?id=jQbEcDDqGb8C&pg=PA110), English transl.of the 2nd ed., 1932.

The previous English translation of the German [Abbildung](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Abbildung) was *transformation* or *correspondence*; see e.g. [Richard Dedekind (1887), page 50](https://books.google.it/books?id=zfTlPWe5QFAC&pg=PA50), 1st English transl., 1901.

Also *correlation* was used; see [D.Hilbert (1904), page 348](https://ia800202.us.archive.org/4/items/jstor-27899603/27899603.pdf), Engl.transl.*The Monist* (1905).